# Getting only temperature from Yahoo Weather

Tags: json, yql

I want to get the temperature from Yahoo weather API, I am using the following code:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where location%3D"48906"&format=json
```

I just want to retrieve the temperature and not anything else.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I just want to retrieve the temperature" ? Do you want the temperature json property (C or F)  inside units or the high/low inside forecast json property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I just want to retrieve the temperature and not anything else.

Its a 2-step process, you need to build the request and then crunch the result to get the temperature.

please see: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/05/weather-forecast-geolocation-jquery/

and

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/08/22/adding-weather-to-your-site-with-jquery-and-yql/